# Issue with positional parameters in class constructor

Tags: python, qt

I'm working on a Qt app right now in python and I've having a few issues with some positional parameters.

I have two classes, one named `FrameMark` and another `MarkerCursor`  Both of them subclass the same parent class.  `FrameMark` works fine, but when I try to instantiate `MarkerCursor`, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "frame_controls.py", line 360, in <module>
    main()
  File "frame_controls.py", line 355, in main
    w = Window(sys.argv[1])
  File "frame_controls.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.timeline = Timeline(self.frames)
  File "frame_controls.py", line 322, in __init__
    self.markerCursor = MarkerCursor(None, self)
TypeError: MarkerCursor() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

The `__init__()` functions are setup like so:

```
    def __init__(self, frame, parent=None, scene=None):
        super(FrameMark, self).__init__(parent, scene)

    # ...

    def __init__(self, parent=None, scene=None):
        super(MarkerCursor, self).__init__(parent, scene)
```

And here is where I instantiate them:

```
    for i in range(len(self.frames)):
        mark = FrameMark(self.frames[i], None, self)
        self.marks.append(mark)

    # Make the cursor marker
    self.markerCursor = MarkerCursor(None, self)
```

I have no idea why `FrameMark` is working fine, but `MarkerCursor` is giving me the error.  Thanks!

Comment: What is the `__init__` signature of the superclass that they inherit from?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't shadow `MarkerCursor` with something else ?

Comment: @BrenBarn they both inherit from a `QGraphicsRectItem`, the documentation is here http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qgraphicsrectitem.html, but I'm not sure if that's the problem.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers What do you mean by "shadowing?"  Do you mean overloading?  If so, there are no other places where `MarkerCursor` is written in the source.

Comment: Possibly, but still the name `MarkerCursor` may not be bound to what you assume it is - for example a star import can easily rebind a previously imported name. Just drop in the debugger at that line and inspect what `MarkerCursor` really refers to at that point.

Comment: Oh and yes: if `MarkerCursor` is not a pure Python class, it may expect named arguments for `parent` and `scene`.

Comment: I just realized what the problem was.  I had put down `def MarkerCursor` instead of `class MarkerCursor`.  i r idot

Answer (score 0):

The issue arose because because I accidentally put down:

```
def MarkerCursor(QGrapihcsRectItem):
```

Instead of:

```
class MarkerCursor(QGraphicsRectItem):
```

Python thought it was a function I was calling, not a new class instance.